# Forth span of a row overflowing Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website http://westlinebuilders.com, here is my code

```
<div class="row allprj">
    <div class="span4">
        <figure class="frame thumbnail alignnone clearfix">
            <a title="Permanent Link to THE PRESIDENTIAL SUITES" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/the-presidential-suites/" class="image-wrap"><img alt="THE PRESIDENTIAL SUITES" src="http://westlinebuilders.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Westline-Falnir_03-W-.jpg"></a>
        </figure>
        <div style="margin-top: -10px; padding: 0 0 15px;" class="service-box extra">
            <div class="service-box_body">
                <h2 class="title">
                    <a title="Permanent Link to THE PRESIDENTIAL SUITES" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/the-presidential-suites/" class="extra2" style="font-size: 26px !important">THE PRESIDENTIAL SUITES</a>
                </h2>
                <h5 class="sub-title">
                    Falnir                                          
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4  prj">
        <figure class="frame thumbnail alignnone clearfix">
            <a class="image-wrap" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/signature" title="Permanent Link to Westline Signature"><img src="http://westlinebuilders.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/signature-42.jpg" alt="Signature"></a>
        </figure>
        <div style="margin-top: -10px; padding: 0 0 15px;" class="service-box extra">
            <div class="service-box_body">
                <h2 class="title">
                    <a class="extra2" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/signature" title="Permanent Link to Signature" style="font-size: 26px !important">Signature</a>
                </h2>
                <h5 class="sub-title">
                    Nanthoor Junction                                           
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <figure class="frame thumbnail alignnone clearfix">
            <a title="Permanent Link to Skydale" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/westline-skydale/" class="image-wrap"><img alt="Skydale" src="http://westlinebuilders.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/West-lineBKN-Pool1_01-420x247.jpg"></a>
        </figure>
        <div style="margin-top: -10px; padding: 0 0 15px;" class="service-box extra">
            <div class="service-box_body">
                <h2 class="title">
                    <a title="Permanent Link to Skydale" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/westline-skydale/" class="extra2" style="font-size: 26px !important">Skydale</a>
                </h2>
                <h5 class="sub-title">
                    Bikkarnakatte                                           
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <figure class="frame thumbnail alignnone clearfix">
            <a title="Permanent Link to Fairmont" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/westline-fairmont-kadri-mangalore-apartments-flats/" class="image-wrap"><img alt="Fairmont" src="http://westlinebuilders.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/fairmont.jpg"></a>
        </figure>
        <div style="margin-top: -10px; padding: 0 0 15px;" class="service-box extra">
            <div class="service-box_body">
                <h2 class="title">
                    <a title="Permanent Link to Fairmont" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/westline-fairmont-kadri-mangalore-apartments-flats/" class="extra2" style="font-size: 26px !important">Fairmont</a>
                </h2>
                <h5 class="sub-title">
                    Kadri                                           
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <figure class="frame thumbnail alignnone clearfix">
            <a title="Permanent Link to Splendid Homes" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/splendid-homes/" class="image-wrap"><img alt="Splendid Homes" src="http://westlinebuilders.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Westline-Kulshekara_small-420x247.jpg"></a>
        </figure>
        <div style="margin-top: -10px; padding: 0 0 15px;" class="service-box extra">
            <div class="service-box_body">
                <h2 class="title">
                    <a title="Permanent Link to Splendid Homes" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/splendid-homes/" class="extra2" style="font-size: 26px !important">Splendid Homes</a>
                </h2>
                <h5 class="sub-title">
                    Kulshekar                                           
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <figure class="frame thumbnail alignnone clearfix">
            <a title="Permanent Link to Bonita" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/westline-bonita-thokkottu-apartments-flats-mangalore/" class="image-wrap"><img alt="Bonita" src="http://westlinebuilders.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/bonita.jpg"></a>
        </figure>
        <div style="margin-top: -10px; padding: 0 0 15px;" class="service-box extra">
            <div class="service-box_body">
                <h2 class="title">
                    <a title="Permanent Link to Bonita" href="http://westlinebuilders.com/portfolio-view/westline-bonita-thokkottu-apartments-flats-mangalore/" class="extra2" style="font-size: 26px !important">Bonita</a>
                </h2>
                <h5 class="sub-title">
                    NH66, Thokkottu                                         
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

, i have row with with 6  but when you resize your browser window the forth div comes down. I have also tried `<div class="row-fluid">` but no luck, can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your code in the body of your question. Live resources are likely to change from their current state, making them useless for potentially-helpful community members and future users of this site with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, it looks like that actually isn't the fourth item being pushed down - in fact, it's the sixth (keep an eye on the content when you resize your browser) which is being pushed to a new line.

The immediate cause of this is that the title *THE PRESIDENTIAL SUITES* in the first item is making the item taller than its siblings, causing the item below it (the fourth one) to be shifted over, and ultimately forcing the sixth item onto a new line.

The root problem though, is that you're trying to create two rows visually with your `.span4` containers, but you only have a single `.row` container around them. If you want two rows using this framework, use two `.row` containers. So instead of what you currently have as your HTML structure:

```
<div class="row allprj">
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4 prj">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You should split the content into two `.row` containers:

```
<div class="row allprj">
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4 prj">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row allprj">
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot finding out the problem, i have reduced the fontsize of the h2 tag, now its working :)